# Switching between MacOS applications when using IPad as side-car

Tags: ipad, sidecar

When using IPad (with docked keyboard) as sidecar, cmd+Tab on iPad seems to get intercepted and switches between iPad apps instead of Mac apps. Rest of the modifiers get transmitted to Mac correctly. Is there a way to customize this shortcut on iPad or another workaround?

Comment: Have you tried re-defining the local, or remote, cmnd+tab as cmnd+shift+tab?

Comment: @SolarMike I couldn't find the setting to redefine those keys

Comment: So no keyboard shortcuts available or editable on your mac in system preferences?

Comment: I couldn't find the keyboard shortcut for CMD+TAB. I did find the other ones

Comment: @SolarMike can you customize cmd+tab on your machine? Where is that shortcut located?